# Solving a system of second-order non-linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of non-linear ODEs:

\begin{eqnarray}
c_1\cdot f_h(x) = c_h + g(x) + x(1-x)^2 \frac{(f_h(x) - f_l(x))^2}{\sigma^2} f_h'(x)+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2(1-x)^2(f_h(x) - f_l(x))^2}{\sigma^2} f_h''(x)\\
c_1\cdot f_l(x) = c_l + g(x) - x^2(1-x) \frac{(f_h(x) - f_l(x))^2}{\sigma^2} f_l'(x) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2(1-x)^2(f_h(x) - f_l(x))^2}{\sigma^2} f_l''(x)\\
\end{eqnarray}

where $c_h, c_l, c_1, \sigma$ are constants. The boundary conditions are:

\begin{equation}
f_h(0) = f_h (1) = f_l(0) = f_l(1) =0
\end{equation}

Has anyone seen analytical solutions to something similar to this?

Comment: Sorry I forgot some important terms initially!

Comment: Are you sure that it should be $c_1\cdot f_h(x)$ in the second equation? Also check if $x(1-x)^2$ and $-x^2(1-x)$ are correct. If it was $f_l(x)$ you could subtract both equations. And introduce $g(x)=f_h(x)-f_l(x) $.

Comment: You are write about the f_h term in the second equation. The other one for sure is correct. I edited the equation to fix this.